# JWT token public/private key pair generator

Tags: jwt, express-jwt

In my Nodejs 12.16.x app, JWT token is generated as below:

```
const token = jwt.sign(
    {
      uid: this.id,
      did: this.device_id,
    },
    process.env.jwtPrivateKey,  //<<==here is the private key
    {
      expiresIn: (parseInt(process.env.jwt_token_expire_days) * 24).toString() + 'h',
      algorithm: 'HS256'  //<<==here is the algorithm
    }
  );
```

What is the public/private key generator I can use to generate public/private key for JWT token? Someone recommends `ssh-keygen`. What is the number of bits shall I choose for algorithm `HS256`?

Also if there is already a private key given, how to find its associated public key?

Comment: JWS `HS256` is _HMAC_ which is not a publickey algorithm and **does not use a public/private key** (which SSH, and `ssh-keygen`, does). The (secret) key for `HS` schemes should be random bits of the same size as the output, possibly encoded if the software wants that; see [RFC 7518 section 3.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7518)

Comment: My understanding is that the private key is used on one server, with public key distributed to other servers for authentication (the token is generated by the private key whose public is presented here).  I am not sure if this is going to render HS256 useless.

Comment: _Publickey_ signature algorithms (also called 'asymmetric', the Latin prefix a- meaning 'not') work as you describe: only the signer holds the private key but the public key can be distributed widely. The HSnnn schemes in JWS are HMAC, which is NOT a publickey or asymmetric algorithm, it is a 'symmetric' algorithm which uses only a single key, which must be secret, not a pair of private and public keys. If you want publickey, don't use HSnnn. If you want HSnnn, it isn't publickey.